# Merge multiple arrays

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of arrays as given below.

```
[
  ["Horse", 8, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Horse", 0, 0, 12, 0],
  ["Horse", 0, 7, 0, 0],
  ["Dog", 1, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Dog", 0, 0, 3, 0],
  ["Dog", 0, 3, 0, 0],
  ["Test", 5, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Test", 0, 0, 2, 0],
  ["Test", 0, 0, 0, 2],
  ["Cat", 5, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Cat", 0, 0, 4, 0],
  ["Cat", 0, 2, 0, 0]
]
```

I want to merge the different arrays who start with the same first elements together and replacing the 0 by the value who are at the same position inside the other array, like the result below.

```
[
  ["Horse", 8, 7, 12, 0],
  ["Dog", 1, 3, 3, 0],
  ["Test", 5, 0, 2, 2],
  ["Cat", 5, 2, 4, 0]
]
```

So far I have this function:

```
array.each_with_index do |line, idx|
  if array[idx+1].present? && line[0] == array[idx+1][0]
    line.each_with_index do |l, i|
      if l != 0 && array[idx+1][i] == 0
        array[idx+1][i] = array[idx][i]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it is not completely what I'm trying to do, but i'm close. Does anyone have some insights?

Comment: Explain "this array". What logic gives you that? The code you presented will not substitute for that because reading through your code to figure out your intention is an extra burden that the readers should not do, and the fact that is it not complete means that we cannot get the logic by parsing your code.

Comment: In what way do you want to merge the arrays? There are indefinitely many ways to do that. What do you mean by "correct value"? How is "sorting" relevant to your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not certain what the question is, but assuming that the array given is `arr`, you can get the result by:

```
arr
.group_by(&:first)
.map{|k, v| [k, *v.transpose.drop(1).map{|a| a.inject(:+)}]}
```

or as pointed out by Cary Swoveland:

```
arr
.group_by(&:first)
.map{|k, v| [k, *v.transpose.drop(1).map(&:sum)]}
```

Result:

```
[
  ["Horse", 8, 7, 12, 0],
  ["Dog", 1, 3, 3, 0],
  ["Test", 5, 0, 2, 2],
  ["Cat", 5, 2, 4, 0]
]
```

Comment: I thought same nearly way :)

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted to do thanks a lot ! And i didn't know about transpose, so thank for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your initial array of arrays is stored in `arr`:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [0] * 4 }) do |(name, *vals), acc|
  (0...vals.size).each { |i| acc[name][i] += vals[i] }
end.map { |k, v| [k, *v] }
#⇒ [["Horse", 8, 7, 12, 0],
#   ["Dog", 1, 3, 3, 0],
#   ["Test", 5, 0, 2, 2],
#   ["Cat", 5, 2, 4, 0]]
```

The key to the solution is to maintain a hash and convert it to the array in the very end. The hash is easier to lookup and operate in general.

The accumulator uses the default values to simplify adding new values to.

Comment: This "sums", not "replaces". What if there are multiple replacement candidates for the same place? It is not specified what to do by the OP, and I'm too lazy to make a full answer, so a nitpicky comment it is :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am not sure I follow; the result is as needed and if one wants to replace zeroes then the very simple modification is required: add a guard `if acc[name][i].zero?` in the inner block.

Comment: Yep, this guard will fix the imaginary problem

Comment: There won't be multiple replacement candidates for the same place :)

Comment: @Gauthier this is the worst mistake the developer can do: to rely on the validness of an input.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [["Horse", 8, 0, 0, 0], ["Horse", 0, 0, 12, 0], ["Horse", 0, 7, 0, 0],
       ["Dog",   1, 0, 0, 0], ["Dog",   0, 0,  3, 0], ["Dog",   0, 3, 0, 0],
       ["Test",  5, 0, 0, 0], ["Test",  0, 0,  2, 0], ["Test",  0, 0, 0, 2],
       ["Cat",   5, 0, 0, 0], ["Cat",   0, 0,  4, 0], ["Cat",   0, 2, 0, 0]]

require 'matrix'

arr.each_with_object({}) do |(k,*arr),h|
  h[k] = h.key?(k) ? (h[k] + Vector[*arr]) : Vector[*arr]
end.map { |a,v| [a, *v.to_a] }
  #=> [["Horse", 8, 7, 12, 0],
  #    ["Dog",   1, 3,  3, 0],
  #    ["Test",  5, 0,  2, 2],
  #    ["Cat",   5, 2,  4, 0]]
```

Requiring `'matrix'` loads the class [Vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) as well as [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html). See [Vector::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-c-5B-5D), [Vector#+](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-2B) and [Vector#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-to_a).

This does not require the elements of `arr` be ordered in any way.

Answer (score 0):

with this you won't have limit after the name of animal `["Dog", 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 3, ...]`

```
array.group_by { |obj| obj[0] }.map do |key, values| 
  rest = values.reduce([]) do |memo, value|
    value[1..-1].each_with_index do |item, i|
      memo[i] ||= 0
      memo[i] = [item, memo[i]].max
    end
    memo
  end
  [key] + rest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is simple one,

```
hash = array.group_by(&:first)
hash.map { |k,v| v.map { |x| x[1..-1] }.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}.unshift(k) }
```